# CloudFront: HTTPs do we need to rotate certificates?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, amazon-cloudfront

I just setup [Cloud Front Distribution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-creating-console.html) to front my S3 hosted static website.

The website that is hosted on S3 just uses plain HTTP.

However, after setting up the CloudFront (without specifying anything special for SSL). When I use the browser to navigate to CloudFront distrubtion link xxx.cloudfront.net it auto switches to `https`.

Seems to work fine with https. However, the question is there any issues with credential rotation with CloudFront or will that be handled automatically and Cloudfront endpoint should work without additional maintainance required?

Comment: If you are using the default Cloudfront URL it should be managed for you and you have nothing else to do. If you want to use a custom domain, that might be different depending on your setup.

Answer (score 0):

> Cloudfront endpoint should work without additional maintainance required?

It will work, as this endpoint and its cert are AWS managed. But in case you want to have your own endpoint (e.g., mywebsite.com), you will need to have your own SSL certificate. If you use AWS ACM for that, the SSL certificate from ACM can also be [automatically renewed](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/managed-renewal.html).